# WiX Heat tool cannot harvest info from executables

Tags: wix, dcom, heat

Can anyone confirm that heat works only on DLLs, OCX, maybe some other files, but not on executable files?

The thing is, that I run heat on my COM components DLLs or OCXs (registered through regasm, regsvr32) and it harvests all data in the registry related to the file. However, I have DCOM servers that have lots of info related to themselves in the registry (self registered using /regserver) and the harvesting tool extracts just a minimal information about the file itself but nothing from registry related to the file, NOTHING. Like the resulted wxs file could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="ohserver.exe" Guid="{E8D87743-45B6-459E-A72F-22D9A0D5CE16}">
                <File Id="ohserver.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\ohserver.exe" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

As you see nothing from registry, CLSIDs, ProgIDs, RegistryValues, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Heat does not support harvest self-reg data from .exe servers.

Comment: Then how should I handle the installation of DCOM server's using WiX?

Comment: WiX doesn't have a built-in solution. FireGiant, the company I work for, has a tool that supports .exes: https://www.firegiant.com/products/wix-expansion-pack/. If it's your .exe, you can always get the registration data from the source code and manually author it.

Comment: Thanks Bob for the quick reply. Yes the executable is ours, however since we want to automate the MSI pack generation just manually extract the necessary information from the exe's source code is not the best idea, so I'll probably try your WiX Expansion pack to see how it works. However, I noticed there is also heatwave tool you have, is that part of the expansion pack or it is a separate tool to be purchased separately?

Comment: HeatWave Harvesting is part of the WiX Expansion Pack.

Comment: Does the WiX Expansion Pack also take care for DCOM settings? Let's say after the install of a DCOM server executable, is it capable to set up it's DCOM configuration settings, such as the location the application will run on, or the identity setting that defines which user account will be used to run the app (interactive, launching or a particular user).

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to know if the heatwave has a standalone tool like heat.exe that I can launch from command line & harvest from directory? Secondly, I created a small wix project with VS & tried a simple scenario with HarvestFolder. It extracted all files from my directory, but, didn't harvest related registry (self-reg) data. The HarvestFolder tag doesn't support SelfReg attribute, whereas, HarvestProject does. Can you confirm that if my wix project is a separate project with no references to other product projects, then by simply using HarvestFolder I won't be able to harvest registry data?

Comment: HeatWave Harvesting works through MSBuild; it's not a drop-in for Heat.exe. I'm not sure about how HarvestFolder works, sorry.